# SSH Connection Inside GitLab Runner CI Pipeline Not Able to Verify Host Key

Tags: ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, ssh-keys

I am attempting to have a stage in my GitLab CI pipeline checkout a private GitLab repository but I can't seem to get SSH authentication to work.

On my local machine I created a SSH private/public keypair. I am using my local machine only for creating that keypair and am not using it as a server/GitLab runner.

I have the public key added to my GitLab repository as a Deploy Key. I have the private key as a protected variable called `$GIT_SSH_PRIV_KEY`.

The code below is in a stage and I am just testing right now to see if `ssh -T git@gitlab.com` will authenticate properly.

```
    stage: git_merge
    before_script:
        - apt-get update -qq
        - apt-get install openssh-client -qq
        - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
        - echo "$GIT_SSH_PRIV_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
        # - ssh-add <(echo "$GIT_SSH_PRIV_KEY")
        - mkdir -p ~/.ssh && touch ~/.ssh/known_hosts
        - echo $"SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS" >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
        - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
    script:
        - ssh -T git@gitlab.com
```

The error I receive in the pipeline is `Host Key verification failed` so I am not sure where my issue is at currently.

Comment: `- echo $"SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS"` <-- `$` and `"` are in the wrong order.

Answer (score 1):

> I have the public key added to my GitLab repository as a Deploy Key. I have the private key as a protected variable called `$GIT_SSH_PRIV_KEY`.

But, as [documented by GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/#verifying-the-ssh-host-keys), you have to create the new [variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/README.html#gitlab-cicd-environment-variables) with `SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS` as "`Key`", and as a "Value" add the output of `ssh-keyscan` (because the [error message is related to `~/.ssh/known_hosts`](https://askubuntu.com/a/202540/5470)).

```
## Use the domain name
ssh-keyscan example.com

## Or use an IP
ssh-keyscan 1.2.3.4
```

> By using a variable instead of ssh-keyscan directly inside `.gitlab-ci.yml`, it has the benefit that you don’t have to change `.gitlab-ci.yml` if the host domain name changes for some reason.
> Also, the values are predefined by you, meaning that if the host keys suddenly change, the CI/CD job doesn’t fail, so there’s something wrong with the server or the network.

As commented, that variable must be used as `"$SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS"`, not `$"SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS"`.